# Simplifying expression quartic x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to simplify the expression:

$3x^4-x^3+4x^2-5x-5$

by finding the different roots of x? I tried by the Rational Roots test, but couldn't find one easily.

Comment: See also here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html

Comment: In title, *quartic* would be better that *quadratic*.

Comment: Like all quartics the roots of this one are expressible in closed form, but like most quartics those expressions are so complicated that they are unhelpful for most purposes. In fact, this polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, that is, it does not factor as a product of polynomials of lower degrees with rational coefficients.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hint: One solution is given by $$\left\{x\to \frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt{-31-\frac{716}{\sqrt[3]{3079+6 \sqrt{422655}}}+4
   \sqrt[3]{3079+6 \sqrt{422655}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{31}{18}+\frac{179}{9
   \sqrt[3]{3079+6 \sqrt{422655}}}-\frac{1}{9} \sqrt[3]{3079+6 \sqrt{422655}}-\frac{313}{18
   \sqrt{-31-\frac{716}{\sqrt[3]{3079+6 \sqrt{422655}}}+4 \sqrt[3]{3079+6
   \sqrt{422655}}}}}\right\}$$